# opering arrays into json array from php session files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I`m maintenance a system, but some legacy codes are in PHP, but not will be touch right now,

After login in dashboard, asks for a php class to verify is the person has $_session valid

if yes the return is like

```
{"http":"210","data":{"nome":"Pedro Henrique","email":"pedro.hsdeus@#####.com","username":"chr###s","password":"######"}}
```

I am using

```html
var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
switch(obj.http)
{
case 210:case '210': 
break;
                        
case 403:case '403': header("Location: ../index.html"); 
break;
}
```

My doubt how to read the second array it have $session data to use in html page.

Originally the dashbord was in PHP5 now migrating to 8 with no HTML.php pages

Comment: Sorry what second array are you talking about? No arrays of any kind are shown in your question.

Comment: Also `header("Location` is PHP code, that won't work in JavaScript. Use window.location instead

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) on PHP side and [$.parseJason()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) an jQuery side.

Comment: It alread have in PHP $response = array('http'=>'210','data'=>$user_data);   echo json_encode($response);

Comment: And I have to operate the array data.

Comment: Then you must use $.parseJson() in the Jquery/JS and then use the JavaScript JSON syntax.